# calling methods in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python.I read that every identifier is an object reference in python (including primitive data types). We use object reference to call object methods. For example

```
a="hello world"
```

Here `a` is a reference to string object and i use this reference to call string object methods.But what I found today is that I can directly use the object itself instead of a reference. i.e both
`a.upper()` and `"hello world".upper()` are valid.What i need to know the underlying logic of calling an object method in python.How am I able to use both object reference and object itself to call methods. Is there a difference in above two methods??

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html, http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question suggests that you are very new to object-oriented programming. I would suggest that you go through the Python tutorial at docs.python.org/tutorial/ which will answer this question alongside many others.

Comment: @HerrKaputt yeah,i'm a noob...Thnx,i'll look into that

Answer (score 1):

Reference variables are just names for objects.  `"hello world"` is just an unnamed object - an object doesn't need a name to call methods on it, it just needs to exist.